# Send ArrayList value in URL

Tags: java, android, json, httprequest

I need send the arraylist values for: starDateS, endDateS, starHourS, endHourS and intervalS. In the parameters: fecha1, fecha2, desde, hasta, slotH. Of one url

```
   private String intervalS [] = new String[30];

    private String starHourS [] = new String[30];

    private String endHourS [] = new String[30];

    private String starDateS [] = new String[30];

    private String endDateS [] = new String[30];

IdProf="258";


intervalSelected = (String) adapSpinnerIntervalT.getItem(position);

intervalS [0] = intervalSelected;

starHourSelected = (String) adapSpinnerStarH.getItem(position);

starHourS[0] = starHourSelected;

endHourSelected = (String) adapSpinnerEndH.getItem(position);

endHourS[0] = endHourSelected;

mStarDate = mDpDay + " " + mMonth + "," + mDpYear;

starDateS[0] = mStarDate;

mEndDate = mDpDay + " " + mMonth2 + "," + mDpYear;

endDateS [0] = mEndDate;
```

ServerConnection.setDataAvailab= "http://www.saludvitale.com/app/disponibilidad?idUser=";

```
private void setDataAvaliability (String IdProf, String[] endDateS, String[] starDateS, String[] intervalS, String[] starHourS, String[] endHourS) {

UrlDataAva=ServerConnection.setDataAvaliab+IdProf+"&fecha2="+endDateS[0]+"&fecha1="+starDateS[0]+"&slotH="+intervalS[0]+"&desde="+starHourS[0]+"&hasta="+endHourS[0];

   try {

            JsonObject objPayload = new JsonObject();
            ServerConnection.SendHTTPRequet(getActivity(), UrlDataAva, objPayload, new OnComplete() {
                @Override
                public void onRequestComplete(Exception e, String result) {
                    handleDataAva(result);
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The url send should be like this: http://www.saludvitale.com/app/disponibilidad?idUser=253&fecha2%5B%5D=30+June%2C+2017&fecha1%5B%5D=21+June%2C+2017&slotH%5B%5D=1+hora&desde%5B%5D=01%3A00+AM&hasta%5B%5D=06%3A00+AM

As I do so that % 5B% 5D is added in the parameters of my url, as in the previous one.

Comment: I am confused...what is happening vs what you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry, what happens is that it does not recognize the parameters as arrays so it does not add% 5B% 5D. I want to know how to place the parameters so that in the url is added% 5B% 5D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this with the Apache StringUtils from Apache commons

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(setDataAvaliab+IdProf);
builder.append("&fecha=[").append(StringUtils.join(endDateS, ",")).append("]"); //append until each parameter is covered
String url = URLEncoder.encode(builder.toString());
```

Comment: I send this structure: {"id":"258","fecha2":"[10 January,2017]","fecha1":"[20 January,2017]","desde":"[09:00 AM]","hasta":"[05:00 PM]","slot":"[1 hora]"}  .But i need send that: {"id":"253","fecha2":["30 June, 2017"],"fecha1":["21 June, 2017"],"desde":["01:00 AM"],"hasta":["06:00 AM"],"slot":["1 hora"]}. How do I get the quotation marks inside the bracket. Please

Comment: You can escape it and put "[\"21 June, 2017\"]" to get the quotation marks in the